# Firefox & Chrome, trying to use a accessible collapse content

Tags: jquery, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I'm testing the [JQuery Collapsible Plugin](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/expand_and_collapse_content_accessibly_with_progressive_enhancement_jquery/) in my page using JAWS screen reader, but when I click in the link to show the hidden data and use the `p` keyword, the next element outside the hidden data is readed.

I tested in Chrome (latest version), Firefox 11 and Internet Explorer 8. Only IE reads correctly the data.

I tried the demo in the link and it works well.

My markup is:

```
<div class='well' id="dialogDadosFuncionario" aria-describedby="dialogDescription">
  <div role="group" aria-describedby="dialogDescription">
    <h4 id="dialogDescription">
      My Data
    </h4>
    <table summary='My data...'>
    ...
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- In Chrome and FF this table is readed instead of the table above -->
<table summary='something...'>
</table>
```

And I'm using `$('#dialogDescription').collapsible();` to trigger the plugin.

What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify by the p keyword? I skimmed the Filament link, and I would try the following:

```
<table summary="My Data">
  <capton>
   <h4 class="...">My Data</h4> <!--use the hide/show classes -->
  </caption>
...
</table>
```

The caption puts a title on the table. It is not good to give the summary and title the same value, I assume you just did it for example purposes. This will be announced as Table, heading level 4, My data, my data, [continue reading table].

You may need to wrap a div around the `<h4>` to do the show/hide correctly.

### **NEW Solution**

It looks like you are feeding the function the ID and not an HTML tag. Try:  `$('h4').collapsible();`

Comment: Hi Ryan. Thanks for your response! The p keyword is used to read the next content (in order) of the page. So in my example i was expecting that the screen reader reads "table my data" but reads "table something". If I put a `h4` in the caption and use this as collapsible, the plugin breaks and the show/hide don't work for the table.

Comment: Oh ok, you are expecting the user to use the p hotkey if they are using a screen reader. The p hotkey actually jumps to the next `<p>` or HTML paragraph tag. Since everything is a table or a `<div>` in your sample, it will skip everything. Have you tried removing the `<h4>`?

Comment: Using `p` Jaws read the next text, it doesn't need to be a paragraph. In my sample the reader jumps to the second table and I'm trying to make him jump do the first table after the `<h4>`.

Comment: Interesting, I wonder if Freedom scientific changed something because it used to ignore all text besides the ones in `<P>`'s.

Comment: I've tried your second solution. This don't change anything because is just the way you select the element to be collapsible...

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide more information that is happening? Beyond that you may want to send filament a note. The examples they have only show/hide lists. While I don't see why you couldn't show/hide a table, something else might be happening.